# How to count the number of record with a key in Spark using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My data shows some pair of words and the count of how many times this pair occurs. For example:

```
[("('best', 'it')", 3), ("('best', 'of')", 4), ("('best', 'the')", 3), ("('best', 'was')", 3), ("('it', 'of')", 11), ("('it', 'the')", 11)]
```

My goal is to count for a word, how many pairs it exists. For example, I want to get:

```
best 4
it 3
```

One tricky thing is that "it" not only occurs in

```
("('it', 'of')", 11), ("('it', 'the')", 11)
```

but also occurs in

```
('best', 'it')", 3)
```

Thus the program needs somehow identify that.

How should I achieve this in Spark using Python? I'm a newbie so appreciate your help!

Comment: To make it work with spark (not sure if your list of pairs is big enough to justify a spark usage) you should create a dataframe from your list. Afterwards it should be some kind of groupBy in the dataframe

Answer (score 4):

First, create pyspark dataframe from the data.

```
df = sql.createDataFrame(
 [("('best', 'it')", 3),\
  ("('best', 'of')", 4),\
  ("('best', 'the')", 3),\
  ("('best', 'was')", 3),\
  ("('it', 'of')", 11),\
  ("('it', 'the')", 11)],
  ['text', 'count'])

df.show()

+---------------+-----+
|           text|count|
+---------------+-----+
| ('best', 'it')|    3|
| ('best', 'of')|    4|
|('best', 'the')|    3|
|('best', 'was')|    3|
|   ('it', 'of')|   11|
|  ('it', 'the')|   11|
+---------------+-----+
```

Then, convert the strings of `text` in `Array`, explode the `text` and `groupby`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import ast

convert_udf = F.udf(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x), ArrayType(StringType()) )

df = df.withColumn('text', convert_udf('text'))\
       .withColumn('text', F.explode('text'))\
       .groupby('text').count()

df.show() 

+----+-----+                                                                    
|text|count|
+----+-----+
| was|    1|
|  it|    3|
| the|    2|
|  of|    2|
|best|    4|
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with RDD, you can use reduceByKey for this case

```
>>> rdd.collect()
[("('best', 'it')", 3), ("('best', 'of')", 4), ("('best', 'the')", 3), ("('best', 'was')", 3), ("('it', 'of')", 11), ("('it', 'the')", 11)]
>>> rddMap = rdd.map(lambda x: x[0][1:-1].split(',')).flatMap(lambda x: [(i.replace("'","").strip(),1) for i in x])
>>> rddMap.collect()
[('best', 1), ('it', 1), ('best', 1), ('of', 1), ('best', 1), ('the', 1), ('best', 1), ('was', 1), ('it', 1), ('of', 1), ('it', 1), ('the', 1)]
>>> rddReduce = rddMap.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).map(lambda x: x[0]+','+str(x[1]))

>>> for i in rddReduce.collect(): print(i)
... 
best,4
it,3
of,2
the,2
was,1
```